# Syntax error: missing : after property (jQuery validate)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am building a set of jQuery validate rules to be used for a form prototype.

I am getting a JS error with my code. Chromes complains with the error

```
[14:30:27.722] SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

at the location specified in the code comments.

here is the code:

```
    $.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element, regexpr) {          
        return regexpr.test(value);
    }, "Entree invalide");

    $('#mainform').validate({
        rules: {
            form-nocivique: { //Chrome complains here
                required: true,
                digits: true
            },
            form-rue: "required",
            form-province: "required",
            form-codepostal: {
                required: true,
                regex: /([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d){3}/i
            }
        },
    });
```

Any idea why?

Comment: see @Pointy's answer and, not related to your issue and maybe not your complete code pasted, but you should remove extra comma after setting rules, IE8 would complain about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property names (some of them) are invalid identifiers.

You can quote it to fix the problem:

```
   rules: {
        "form-nocivique": { //Chrome complains here
            required: true,
            digits: true
        },
```

You can't use `-` in an identifier in JavaScript; it's a token (the "minus" operator).

Comment: Thank you, solved it. Will accept the answer as soon as the timer runs out :)